# Find next occurrence of date

Tags: php

I want to find the next occurrence of date from the current date.

For example, imagine I want to find 20th of the month from current date

If current date is 10th october then return the result 2014-10-20 (Y-m-d)
If current date is 22nd october then return the result 2014-11-20 (Y-m-d)

Comment: *If current day > requested day then increment month by 1...*

Comment: 2014-11-20 isn't 20th october

Comment: @deceze imagine i have a date 20th july 2014 and current date is 10th october 2014, now the result should be 20th october 2014. I am making a rent system and i want to update all the rent from the date rent was last recieved to the next date from current month.

Comment: That's still pretty trivial... all you need are a few comparison operations and a little bit of math. Please do try to work it out yourself.

Comment: @deceze i actually made a solution just now. Is there any other good method then this?


$oldd= date("Y-m-d",strtotime("2014-06-20"));

$newdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($oldd."+1months"));

while(strtotime($newdate) <= strtotime(date("Y-m-d")))
{
 $newdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($newdate."+1months"));
}
echo $newdate;
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a solution just now using a while loop.

```
$oldd= "2014-06-20";

$newdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($oldd."+1months"));

while(strtotime($newdate) <= strtotime(date("Y-m-d")))
{
    $newdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($newdate."+1months"));
}
echo $newdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

manually and pass that to strtotime(). The time information you need to extract from the reference time string. Like this:

```
$refdate = '2014-02-25 10:30:00';
$timestamp = strtotime($refdate);

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',
    strtotime("next Thursday " . date('H:i:s', $timestamp), $timestamp)
);
```

same results could be achieved using string concatenation:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("next Thursday", $timestamp)
    . ' ' . date('H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

another way, you can use methods of `DateTime` object, PHP has really rich API in dealing with date time.

```
$current_date = new DateTime('2014-06-20');

if ($current_date->format('d') >= 20) {
    // $current_date->modify('last day of this month')->modify("+20 days");
    $current_date->modify('first day of next month')->modify("+19 days");
}else{
    $current_date->modify('first day of this month')->modify("+19 days");
}
echo $current_date->format("Y-m-d");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php